# HTML background Gradient repeating

Tags: css, gradient

Just implemented a gradient background into a webpage that extends past the fold. The gradient works and looks perfect up until the footer where a 10 pixel in height gap is which is of the color of the beginning of the gradient. Thus it seems the gradient is "repeating"

http://s30.postimg.org/6r64lcqkx/problem.png

There it is. I've attempted a HTML/Body height fix aka:

CSS:

```
html {
   height:100%
}

body {
   min-height:100%;
}
```

but that just made things worse by repeating the gradient at the exact height of the window.

Here is the code for the body element at the moment

CSS:

```
body {
    background: #650000; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #650000 0%, #d40000 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#650000), color-stop(100%,#d40000)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #650000 0%,#d40000 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #650000 0%,#d40000 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #650000 0%,#d40000 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #650000 0%,#d40000 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#650000', endColorstr='#d40000',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    font-family: 'helveticaneue_bold';
    font-size:11px;
}
```

courtesy of Wijnand: http://jsfiddle.net/ey7kfog3/

Comment: Add a JSFiddle with your code.. It is easier to help with the actual code, and not just an image.. :-)

Comment: I made a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ey7kfog3/

Comment: Cheers Wijnand, added to post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`body` has a **margin** by default in most if not all browsers. Thus the vertical scrollbar when in fact you've set a height of 100% and not set more than 100...

In DevTools or Firebug, you can display these default values (Firebug: HTML / Style on right, it's in the dropdown) and see that there's a margin of 8px on body thus a body taller than 100% by 16px, the exact value of repeated gradient (in Firefox).

Just add **`body { margin: 0; }`** and no more scrollbar or repeated gradient.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ey7kfog3/4/

EDIT: it's present in most reset.css and alike like Eric Meyer's one or [normalize](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/)

Comment: This made me review my custom css as I'm using normalize. It was a -margin i'd put on a class that was being used as a container. Got rid of the margin as it was for test purposes anyway and now it all works fine.

My bad, this is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it for u: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ey7kfog3/1/)

The CSS:

```
body, html {
height:100%;
width: 100%;
}
.background {
background: #650000; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #650000 0%, #d40000 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#650000),            color-stop(100%,#d40000)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #650000 0%,#d40000 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #650000 0%,#d40000 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #650000 0%,#d40000 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #650000 0%,#d40000 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#650000',         endColorstr='#d40000',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
font-family: 'helveticaneue_bold';
font-size:11px;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}
```

The HTML:

```
<div class="background"></div>
```

And then you can,

```
postition: fixed;
```

it so you get the same effect as if it were the body

Hope it works for u

Answer (score 0):

it looks weird, i don't know why it is working like this!
Quickest workaround will be

```
body {
   min-height:94%;
}
```

look this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ey7kfog3/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use div as a container. I have used position fixed with setting 0 to left, right, top, bottom and added overflow auto as it should work as body container.

Also hide scroll-bar from body. Check your updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ey7kfog3/3/).

```
html {
   height:100%
}

body {
   min-height:100%; overflow:hidden;
}
div.test {position:fixed; top:0; bottom:0; left:0; right:0; overflow:auto;
    background: #650000; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #650000 0%, #d40000 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#650000), color-stop(100%,#d40000)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #650000 0%,#d40000 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #650000 0%,#d40000 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #650000 0%,#d40000 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #650000 0%,#d40000 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#650000', endColorstr='#d40000',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    font-family: 'helveticaneue_bold';
margin:0;
}
```